# Call abstract java class from jruby with a generic

Tags: jruby

Currently facing an issue while writing a similar java class in Jruby.

**Example:**

**In Java:**

```
 public class Client extends ClientConnection<ChannelType> {

  //do some stuff

 }
```

**In Jruby:**

```
class Client < Java::'package_name'::ClientConnection

//do some stuff

end
```

**Don't know how to pass ChannelType class in Jruby code while rewriting the Client class**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short version is, you can't unfortunately.

The JRuby wiki explains it as such here (https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/CallingJavaFromJRuby#beware-of-java-generics):

> If a Java class is defined with Java generics, the types are erased during compilation for backwards compatibility. As a result, JRuby will have problems with automatic type conversion. For example, if you have a Map, it will be seen as a simple Map, and JRuby will not be able to determine the correct types using reflection.

Comment: Are we unable to use / call java methods that use generics ?? That's like umm _most_ of java.  I do hope not : I am warming to the idea of using `jruby` for a middle tier in place of java (and despite being huge `scala` fan)

Comment: You can use generic methods, but you will not be able to use the specific types on them and JRuby won't do any of its automatic type conversions on them. So to get the proper type conversions you'll likely have to do some manual work. But generally speaking, you can work around this limitation and you aren't prohibited from calling generic methods in any way.

Comment: Ah!  hey do you have any examples of the `manual work` that could be used as a starting point/ template?  In any case this is good news!

Comment: Sadly I don't see any good examples anywhere right away, but maybe take a look at JRuby's Map tests: 
 https://github.com/jruby/jruby/blob/master/spec/java_integration/types/map_spec.rb 

That should give you a good idea of what "just works". The problems really rather come if you have e.g. a Java Map<String, ?> and then on the Ruby end do something like `map.put("a",...)` to it, then it won't bark at you or do the conversion of `"a"` from RubyString to Java string for you. You just have to watch out for Ruby and Java type mixing because generics won't that for you like in Java, that's all.

Comment: that's fair. as long as it's just "buyer beware" and not "Entry forbidden" i'm good here.